# How to deploy war using CLI to individual instance than deploying to ha-server-group for jboss 6.0 eap?

Tags: deployment, jboss, distributed

### Jboss version= 6.0 EAP

Need your inputs around Jboss deployment, currently we were deploying custom war files using jboss cli command like deploy  custom.war --server-groups=ha-server-group

We have a requirement to deploy custom war into individual jboss servers (ha-server-1,ha-server-2) rather server group name.

Do we have any jboss cli commands which can be used for deploying war file into individual server….?.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but in Domain mode we cant deploy application on specific server which is part of the server-group.
If you deploy application on server group then it will be get deployed on all servers which are part of that server-group.In EAP 6 Domain mode, we can deploy application on server-group only.

If you want to deploy application on specific server instance then you can create new server group.